# Import file in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Page contains this `form`:

```
<form target="PID297_TGT_FRAME" action="/app/upload/57aa897a64d9" class="form form-default" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden">
        <input name="PID297_file" class="file-upload" type="file">
        <div aria-pressed="false" role="button" class="v-button" tabindex="0">
            <span class="v-button-wrap">
                <span class="v-button-caption">Import</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now I want to upload file to form. After searching stackoverflow I found that it is possible to send file path to `input` with type `file`. So I did this:

```
var elem = Driver.FindElement(By.Name("PID297_file")).SendKeys(filePath);
```

Unfortunelly I am getting `Exception` with Message:

```
Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you try adding a wait for visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element needs to be visible for selenium to access it.
If there is some other action that enables the file upload, do it first in selenium code.

Comment: Adding `Driver.RunScript("jQuery(\"input\").attr(\"visibility\", \"visible\");");` did nothing. Still element is not visible.

Comment: Is the Input box visible to the user ? Is it hidden because of some class? See this question also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685415/upload-file-to-hidden-input-using-protractor-and-selenium?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

...implies that the **WebDriver** instance was unable to locate the element as it was not *visible*.

The positive take away from this message is the desired element is **present** within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) but not **visible** possibly as it is not within the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

### Solution

You need to bring the desired element within the *Viewport* before invoking `SendKeys()` as follows:

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("input.file-upload[name$='_file']"))).SendKeys(filePath);
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@class='file-upload' and contains(@name,'_file')]"))).SendKeys(filePath);
  ```

Comment: Visible is not determined by whether the element is in the viewport. You can look at the source and see for yourself.